# Correct usage of JPA in jsp application

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm trying to develop a simple JSP based web application with JPA and would like to know the correct usage for developing one.

In my sample application I have two JSP pages and a simple Java class to perform database operations. Both the JSP files use this Java class to perform DB operations.

I've annotated this class with `@Stateless` and injected an Entity manager as follows:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myjpa") 
EntityManager em;
```

In my `persistence.xml` I've set the following property:

```
<property 
    name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
    value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"
/>
```

I'm calling the class in JSP using JNDI (as the class is annotated for a stateless session bean) as follows:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

Sample sample = (Sample) ic.lookup("java:app/" + application.getContextPath() + "/Sample");
```

I'm facing the following scenarios:

1. When I try to use a transaction `em.getTransaction().begin()/commit()` for insert and update, it says can not use transaction with JTA case.
2. So in the constructor code of my Java class I use the following code:

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();

properties.put("javax.persistence.transactionType", "RESOURCE_LOCAL");

emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myjpa",properties);

em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

I tried to use transactions like `em.getTransaction().begin()/commit()`. 
But in this case the pages become very slow after 2-3 database update and load operations. Though I'm not getting any exception. Overall in my table I'm having less than 25 records.

To me it seems as if it is waiting internally for some operation to complete.

At the same time I also feel that the way I'm using JPA is wrong and hence soliciting advice for the correct approach for doing even simple web apps with JSP and JPA.

While I'm still exploring Java EE, in case you have any specific reference for such cases I'll like to read and look them too.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing the persistence from inside the JSP, especially if you're using a proper EE app. Any reason why you don't have beans to provide this functionality?

Comment: I'm trying to develop simple stuff to understand things. in this case I'm doing the persistence in my java class stateless bean. Just that I'm calling that bean in a jsp. Within the jsp there is no direct persistence/db operation. All the db calls are through bean class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always strive to use JTA transactions which means the container will handle the transaction demarcations. In your case if you want to handle transactions by your self, you need to define it as a bean managed transaction. So in your EJB class, after the @Stateless annoattions, you should define the following annotation;

```
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
```

The usual best practice is to let the container handle the transactions, unless there is some explicit reason for you to use Bean managed transactions.

Comment: I agree that letting container handling the transaction is better. I added transactions as database changes were not getting reflected. And i though it could be because of db transactions are not getting committed. After adding transaction code & related code changes the db changes are getting reflected. But the app is slow.  May be I should spend time on why with simple JTA option the DB is not reflecting changes.

Answer (score 1):

> At the same time I also feel that the way I'm using JPA is wrong

Your usage indeed seems wrong. If you're using a (stateless) session bean you do not have to fiddle with `em.getTransaction().begin()/commit()` and you definitely don't have to use code such as `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory`.

You also don't have to set the property `org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform`.

A session bean automatically manages the transaction for you, and within a Java EE AS (such as JBoss AS) you don't have to configure any transaction manager or similar things.

An example:

```
@Stateless
public class UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void add(User user) {
        entityManager.persist(user);
    }
}
```

As for the `persistence.xml` file, something like the following should be enough to get started:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="somePU">
        <jta-data-source>java:app/someDS</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Some more examples:

- http://jdevelopment.nl/sample-crud-app-with-jsf-and-richfaces
- http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2011/08/minimal-3-tier-java-ee-app-without-any.html